# Unable to access 'emailForSignIn' when using FirebaseUI with React and Email Link sign in method

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The FirebaseUI React widget won't recognize authentication links when using the Email Link provider. Using firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href) works, but then I'm unsure how to decrypt the 'emailForSignIn' cookie in order to use the signInWithEmailLink API.

Set up within a basic create-react-app application, running React 16.8.1, firebase 5.8.2 and firebaseui 3.5.2. and react-firebaseui 3.1.2.

I'm happy to handle signInWithEmailLink, but haven't been able to track down a method of grabbing the encoded email that the widget stores. I realize I could prompt a user for an email address, but the kind of defeats the point of using an Email Link!

Would love any suggestions the community has.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import firebase from "firebase";
import "./App.css";

// Configure Firebase.
const config = {
    apiKey: "XXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      isSignedIn: false
    };

    // Configure FirebaseUI.
    uiConfig = {
      signInFlow: "popup",
      signInOptions: [
        {
          provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD
          // requireDisplayName: true
        },
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
      ],
      credentialHelper: "none",
      callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: () => console.log("Signed In!")
      }
    };

    // Listen to the Firebase Auth state and set the local state.
    componentDidMount() {
      this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase
        .auth()
        .onAuthStateChanged(user => this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user }));
      if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
        console.log("auth instance recognizes email link");
      }
    }

    // Make sure we un-register Firebase observers when the component unmounts.
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unregisterAuthObserver();
    }

    handleIsSignInWithEmailLink(ui) {
      if (ui.isPendingRedirect()) {
        console.log("UI instance recogizes email link");
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            {!this.state.isSignedIn ? (
              <div>
                <h1>My App</h1>
                <p>Please sign-in:</p>
                <StyledFirebaseAuth
                  uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
                  firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
                  uiCallback={this.handleIsSignInWithEmailLink.bind(this)}
                />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <h1>My App</h1>
                <p>
                  Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}! You are now signed-in!
                </p>
                <a onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a>
              </div>
            )}
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey @mosse, can you post the error you are getting when the link is opened? Can you inspect the browser network console too for any errors?

Comment: Thanks @bojeil, unfortunately I'm not seeing any errors in the network console or elsewhere. The component mounts and isSignInWithEmailLink returns true, but it seems that StyledFirebaseAuth won't handle the signin for some reason.

Comment: Does it just display the nascar sign-in screen as if nothing happened?

Comment: Exactly that. It simply launches the beginning of the sign-in flow.

Comment: Can you check the network browser console? When you click the sign-in link, do you see any relevant requests going out to `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/...` ?